# Second SELECT query if first SELECT returns 0 rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to speed up a PHP script and I am currently pushing some PHP logic in the Mysql domain of the thing. Is there a way to make a different select query if the first Select returns no rows, or a count of zero ?

Keeping in mind that the first query needs to run first, and the second should **only** be activated if the first one returns an empty set.

```
SELECT * FROM proxies WHERE (A='B') || SELECT * FROM proxies WHERE (A='C')
```

For the above 2 queries I have this code, but it seems to run each query twice (once to count, and once to return). Is there a better way to do this?

```
IF (SELECT count(*) FROM proxies WHERE A='B')>0
    THEN SELECT * FROM proxies WHERE A='B'
ELSEIF (SELECT count(*) FROM proxies WHERE A='C')>0
    THEN SELECT * FROM proxies WHERE A='C'
END IF
```

Comment: You're overcomplicating this. The `count(*)` are a waste. Simply `SELECT * FROM proxies WHERE A='B'` first. If you get zero rows back, then issue `SELECT * FROM proxies WHERE (A='C')`.

Comment: BTW: I believe you have a typo in the question. The last query should end in `WHERE A='C'`, instead of `WHERE A='B'`.

Comment: @Asaph You were right about the typo, thnx

Comment: How many rows are possible for the first SELECT - 1 or more?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

One option would be to use `UNION ALL` with `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM proxies 
WHERE A='B'
UNION ALL
SELECT * 
FROM proxies 
WHERE A='C' AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM proxies 
    WHERE A='B'
)
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3fcc4/2)

This will return rows from the `proxies` table where `A='B'` if they exist.  However, if they don't exist, it will look for those rows with `A='C'`.

Comment: I will try this out and get back to you, but it looks great thnx.

Comment: I'd be curious to know if this is actually faster than letting php handle the logic.  I guess that would partially depend on how frequently A='B' returns nothing.

Answer (score 8):

```
SELECT * 
FROM proxies 
WHERE A=(CASE WHEN
             (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM proxies WHERE A='B') > 0 THEN'B' 
              ELSE 'C' END)
```

**UPDATE**

```
SELECT * 
FROM proxies 
WHERE (
    CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM proxies WHERE A='B' LIMIT 1) > 0 THEN
            (A='B')
         WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM proxies WHERE A='C' LIMIT 1) > 0 THEN
            (A='C')
         WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM proxies WHERE A='D' LIMIT 1) > 0 THEN
            (A='D')
         ELSE 1=2 END)
```

Comment: Thanks Fabien thats a great solution for what i asked, but i was misleadingly simplifying it i guess. The WHERE conditions are more numerous and complicated.

Comment: Thanks!Great Solution!

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
SELECT A INTO @v FROM proxies ORDER BY A LIMIT 1;
SELECT * FROM proxies WHERE A=@v
```

Answer (score 1):

In a general case where you have multiple values for `A` (lets say, 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', etc.) and you want to retrieve only the rows that belong to the lowest value that exists, then you would use the following query. This will work also for the particular case you exposed.

```
SELECT p1.*
FROM proxies p1
LEFT JOIN proxies p2
    ON p1.A > p2.A
WHERE p2.A IS NULL
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7e018d/1)

Answer (score 0):

I think this more or less covers what you're trying to do.  If you need the count of rows returned just get the value from mysqli->num_rows

```
$db = new mySQLi(etc);

//run your first query

$query = "SELECT * FROM proxies WHERE A='B'";
$result = $db->query($query);

//check for rows returned

if($result->num_rows > 0){

    //if there are rows get them

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

        //deal with the results

    }

} else {

    //otherwise run your other query and get those results

    $query = "SELECT * FROM proxies WHERE A='C'";
    $result = $db->query($query);
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

        //deal with the results

    }
}
```

Comment: @Evan Don't bother. Just do it in php. It's more straight forward and it won't perform any worse.