# MySQL: Select from other table if exist, otherwise select from current table

Tags: php, mysql

Can you help me build a SQL query for getting list of data from 2 table where if data exist on second table, it should display data from it, otherwise from table1

**Table 1:**

```
ID | NAME    | AGE 
------------------
1  | John    | 20
2  | Daniel  | 30
3  | Abraham | 30
4  | Donald  | 25
```

**Table 2:**

```
ID | NAME    | AGE 
------------------
1  | John    | 23
2  | Donald  | 24
```

Desired result: John and Donald "*AGE*" get data from Table 2, and the rest from Table1

```
ID | NAME    | AGE 
------------------
1  | John    | 23
2  | Daniel  | 30
3  | Abraham | 30
4  | Donald  | 24
```

See http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9539b0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Second SELECT query if first SELECT returns 0 rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27366107/second-select-query-if-first-select-returns-0-rows)

Comment: Are you using the `id` or `name` to identify data that should be matched?

Comment: @fubar It should be using the ID.

Comment: @fubar, i use Name as unique record to identify, the ID is just autoincr record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An outer join to Records, and test for a NULL value for age. Like this:

```
SELECT c.id
     , c.name
     , IFNULL(r.age,c.age) AS age
  FROM Clients c
  LEFT
  JOIN Records r
    ON r.name = c.name
 ORDER BY c.id
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9539b0/4

Comment: Its work like a charm, it save a lot of time on my big data processing and code, thanks @spencer7593

Answer (score 2):

Tables joined using auto-increment IDs

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.name, IF(t2.id, t2.age, t1.age) AS age
FROM Clients AS t1
LEFT JOIN Records AS t2 ON (t1.id = t2.id)
```

Or tables joined using names

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.name, IF(t2.name, t2.age, t1.age) AS age
FROM Clients AS t1
LEFT JOIN Records AS t2 ON (t1.name = t2.name)
```

Comment: I've edited the first querry and it result as expected ` SELECT t1.id, t1.name, IF(t2.name=t1.name, t2.age, t1.age) AS age
FROM Clients AS t1
LEFT JOIN Records AS t2 ON (t1.name = t2.name) `

Comment: Checking for equality in the `IF` isn't necessary. That's already handled by the `JOIN`.

Comment: `First query` give invalid result John 23, Daniel 24, Abraham 30 and Donald 25, and the `second query` give the result same as table 1, tested on this finddle  [ http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9539b0/1 ]