# Search pattern and remove search string characters if not found and then search it again in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, pattern-matching

I have to write a query which is having a where clause like below:

```
select x from table where col1 like '%6789%';
```

Now the requirement I have is if above query doesn't return anything then search with 678 or 789 or 67 or 89.

How can I achieve this in best optimised way?

Comment: Your search string contains only digit and you want whenever you found some digit you want to get that value. Is this your actual question? or it is based on any specific pattern.

Comment: If I don't get any rows with 6789 pattern then only search for 678. If I don't get any rows with 678 also then search for 789 and so on.

Comment: [`WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(col1, '67(89?)?|7?89')`](https://regex101.com/r/9CGkza/1)?

Comment: Is this for *any* pattern (e.g. a parameter passed in), or specifically `'6789'`?

Answer (score 2):

Search once for any value containing 6, 7, 8 or 9, order by how well the value matches `'6789'` and take the top result.

(Edit: I've added an `instr` expression to prioritise occurrences of the exact string `'6789'` over the JW score, as otherwise `'678 blah'` would rank higher than `'blah 6789'`.)

```
create table demo (col1) as
( select column_value
  from   table(sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll
         ( '6789','678X','X789','67XX','XX89','XXXX','6XXX','X7XX','11111167891111'
         , '167891','Germany 6, England 7 what a great match that was in 1989')) );

select col1
     , utl_match.jaro_winkler_similarity(col1,'6789') as match_rating
     , nullif(instr(col1,'6789'),0) as match_position
from   demo
where  regexp_like(col1,'[6789]')
order by match_position nulls last, match_rating desc;

COL1                                                     MATCH_RATING MATCH_POSITION
-------------------------------------------------------- ------------ --------------
6789                                                              100              1
167891                                                             88              2
11111167891111                                                     59              7
678X                                                               88 
X789                                                               83 
67XX                                                               73 
XX89                                                               66 
6XXX                                                               55 
X7XX                                                               50 
Germany 6, England 7 what a great match that was in 1989           34 

10 rows selected
```

Filter to get the first row (Oracle 12.1 onwards):

```
select col1
from   demo
where  regexp_like(col1,'[6789]')
order by
       nullif(instr(col1,'6789'),0) nulls last
     , utl_match.jaro_winkler_similarity(col1,'6789') desc
fetch first row only;

COL1
-----
6789
```

For older versions:

```
select col1
from   ( select col1
         from   demo
         where  regexp_like(col1,'[6789]')
         order by
                nullif(instr(col1, '6789'),0) nulls last
              , utl_match.jaro_winkler_similarity(col1,'6789') desc )
where rownum = 1;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a9d884/3

Note `'6789'` can be replaced with a variable in PL/SQL:

```
select col1 into :result
from   demo
where  regexp_like(col1,'['||p_pattern||']')
order by
       nullif(instr(col1, p_pattern),0) nulls last
     , utl_match.jaro_winkler_similarity(col1,p_pattern) desc
fetch first row only;
```

Comment: This is an elegant solution but the results becomes erratic when the values in `col1` are longer than the searched pattern, e.g. `67899` and `67890` have the same Jaro Winkler score, so which one should be `rownum = 1`?.

Comment: True, although the OP has not said what should happen if the first pass `where col1 like '%6789%'` returns multiple rows.

Comment: I think the snag is `'11111167891111'` and `'167891'` would both match `like '%6789%'` but would score very differently on edit distance.

Comment: Indeed, and `'167891'` scores the same as `'678X'` (although well above `'Germany 6, England 7 what a great match that was in 1989'`). I'm hoping @user2974954 will clarify the requirement. (Thinking about it,he/she did say `like '%6789%'` was the priority, so  `'167891'` ought to rank higher than `'678X'`. I'll add a tweak.)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve executing different select with order using [UNION ALL](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries004.htm) combined with [NOT EXISTS](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/mysql-5.1-en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html), similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27366107/second-select-query-if-first-select-returns-0-rows)

```
select x from table where col1 like '%6789%'
UNION ALL
select x from table where col1 like '%678%' or col1 like '%789%' 
or col1 like '%67%' or col1 like '%89%'
AND NOT EXISTS (
select x from table where col1 like '%6789%'
)
```