# Second SELECT query in another table if first SELECT returns 0 rows

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I already read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27366107/second-select-query-if-first-select-returns-0-rows/27366483#27366483). But this is on same table. How can I archie that in two or three table like :

```
if (SELECT ViewCode FROM M_VIEW
          WHERE ViewCode=?) //if found return
else (SELECT ViewCode FROM M_Customer
          WHERE CustomerCode=?)
```

Comment: simply consider handling this from the application code instead..

Comment: @RaymondNijland is this possible for write this in one query?

Comment: *"is this possible for write this in one query?"* Possibly ... See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) ... Still how you describe how it should work handling this in the application seams to be much more easy implemented with likely better performance and you don't have to keep track which selects are made....

Answer (score 3):

You can use a solution like the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ViewCode FROM (
    SELECT ViewCode, 'M_VIEW' AS tName FROM M_VIEW WHERE ViewCode = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ViewCode, 'M_Customer' FROM M_Customer WHERE ViewCode = 1
) t GROUP BY tName, ViewCode
HAVING tName = CASE 
    WHEN SUM(tName = 'M_VIEW') > 0 THEN 'M_VIEW' 
    WHEN SUM(tName = 'M_Customer') > 0 THEN 'M_Customer'
    ELSE '' 
END
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=64f67c2d48669f94ea0573450f8627e4)

Comment: This is not working, see this case https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=708c88d86699a13ab053a430e1634d1e. I just changed view_code for m_view row (id 1 & 2). It should return view code 1 because it is in table m_customer instead of nothing. Maybe you should use SUM instead of COUNT ?

Comment: Also if you use SUM instead of COUNT, it should work but you would have to add DISTINCT ViewCode to prevent multiple identical ViewCode value.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another way of doing it, it'll return rows from exactly one table:

```
SELECT ViewCode FROM M_VIEW WHERE ViewCode = @ViewCode
UNION ALL
SELECT ViewCode FROM M_Customer WHERE CustomerCode = @CustomerCode AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM M_VIEW WHERE ViewCode = @ViewCode
)
```

Note that I've replaced `?` with variable names to show which ? means what.

[Demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=4b7e229d9d635287b526cca062b2650e)

Comment: You should add DISTINCT to prevent "duplicate" ViewCode

Comment: No, distinct is not required, only one branch will return row (the branch itself could return duplicates).

Comment: Yes that's what I was meaning !

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that each query should return 0 or 1 row, you could use union all, then order the records and limit, as follows:

```
SELECT ViewCode
FROM (
    SELECT ViewCode, 1 seq FROM M_View WHERE ViewCode = ?
    UNION ALL SELECT ViewCode, 2 FROM M_Customer WHERE CustomerCode = ?
) t
ORDER BY seq
LIMIT 1
```

If the first query (from `M_View`) returns a record, the ordering clause puts it first, and `limit 1`eliminates the potential other record. Else, the (only) matching record (from `M_Customer`) will be selected.

Comment: anyhow going to remove those comments, anyhow as we are wait for the information from the topicstarter before making more assumptions how to possibly read this question ...

Comment: this comment //if found return I mean, if this query `SELECT ViewCode FROM M_VIEW
          WHERE ViewCode=? ` matching record in table M_VIEW it return this record, if not run this second query