# Get result from second select query when first select query returns 0

Tags: sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I have following schema

```
CREATE TABLE BookImage (Id UNSIGNED BIG INT, ImageId UNSIGNED BIG INT, IsDefault INT, 
                           PRIMARY KEY(Id, ImageId));

INSERT OR IGNORE INTO BookImage(Id,ImageId,IsDefault) VALUES (1,10,0);
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO BookImage(Id,ImageId,IsDefault) VALUES (1,11,1);
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO BookImage(Id,ImageId,IsDefault) VALUES (1,12,0);

INSERT OR IGNORE INTO BookImage(Id,ImageId,IsDefault) VALUES (2,20,0);
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO BookImage(Id,ImageId,IsDefault) VALUES (2,21,0);
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO BookImage(Id,ImageId,IsDefault) VALUES (2,22,0);
```

My target is to get a SELECT query to find (ImageId, Id) for given "Id" such that-

1. if IsDefault=1, then return the row
2. if IsDefault=0, then return the row of lowest ImageId

For given table, if I query with Id=1, it should return only (11,1)
                 if I query with Id=2, it should return only (20,2) because there is not IsDefault=1 for Id=2.

I need a sqlite select query to achieve that. I have tried the query from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27366107/second-select-query-if-first-select-returns-0-rows/27366483#27366483) but it is not working

```
SELECT * 
FROM BookImage 
WHERE Id=1 AND IsDefault=1
UNION ALL
SELECT * 
FROM BookImage 
WHERE Id=1 ORDER BY ImageId ASC LIMIT 1 AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM BookImage 
    WHERE Id=1 AND IsDefault=1 LIMIT 1 
)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/e094e/1/0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `ROW_NUMBER()` window function:

```
SELECT Id, ImageId
FROM (
  SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY IsDefault DESC, ImageId) rn
  FROM BookImage
) b
WHERE rn = 1 AND Id = ?
```

Replace `?` with the `Id` that you search for.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3FjDriKXhgxkVwi4JG7zYJ/5).

Another way:

```
SELECT Id, ImageId
FROM BookImage
WHERE Id = ?
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY IsDefault DESC, ImageId)
LIMIT 1
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3FjDriKXhgxkVwi4JG7zYJ/8).

For older versions of SQLite that do not support window functions:

```
SELECT Id, ImageId 
FROM BookImage
WHERE Id = ?
ORDER BY IsDefault DESC, ImageId
LIMIT 1;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3FjDriKXhgxkVwi4JG7zYJ/15).
Results for `Id = 1`:

```
| Id  | ImageId |
| --- | ------- |
| 1   | 11      |
```

Results for `Id = 2`:

```
| Id  | ImageId |
| --- | ------- |
| 2   | 20      |
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But it is not the exact thing I am looking for. If I search with Id=1, it should retrun (11,1) only. If I query with id=2 then it should return only (20,2).

Comment: Check my edited answer. Replace ? with the id that you search for.

Comment: Yes this exactly I am looking for. But your statement is failing here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/e094e
Could you have a look?

Comment: @JohnCooper check another simpler way.

Comment: I guess that the fiddle in your link uses an older version of SQLite that does not support window functions.

Comment: Yes, I guess so, I am checking whether my system's version supports window functions or not :(

Comment: No this is not the case. It uses SQLite 3.31.1. I just checked. So I don't know why it fails. All the queries work fine in any other environment

Comment: If you want to use it in Android it will not work. Android as far as I know uses an older version. I will post another query.

Comment: No I don't use it with Android, I checked with my system's, window functions are failing there also. (SQLite 3.7.17 2013-05-20)

Comment: I think that the last query is the simplest.

Comment: Yes!! your last 2 queries worked with the SQLite version (3.7.17) I am working working with. Definitely this is an expert answer, can't vote you more :D

Comment: I removed these queries because I posted a simpler query. Check it.