# Run second query if first returns nothing, if first returns row then return that row

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I am trying to run this MySQL query from PHP app.

```
SELECT * FROM LIVE WHERE STATUS=1 AND (CRITERIA='demo' OR CRITERIA='all' OR CRITERIA='1' OR CRITERIA='1E')
```

Which is working perfectly. However I want that if this query returns nothing then it should execute another query somewhat like this.

```
SELECT * FROM LIVE WHERE STATUS=0 AND (CRITERIA='demo' OR CRITERIA='all' OR CRITERIA='1' OR CRITERIA='1E')
```

I have tried multiple things like SELECT IF or SELECT IFNULL but none of them seems to work.
What am I doing wrong? Basically I want that if the first query returns row then give that but if not then run the second query.

Now I saw this question on stackoverflow - [Second SELECT query if first SELECT returns 0 rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27366107/second-select-query-if-first-select-returns-0-rows) . I tried it but in return i got this error
Unrecognized statement type. (near "IF" at position 0)

Comment: I think you should use `CASE` in the `SELECT` but currently its a bit hard to visualize what you're trying to achieve. If you have sample data, results of your current query and your expected result, it would be much easier to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the following logic:

```
SELECT *
FROM LIVE
WHERE CRITERIA IN ('demo', 'all', '1', '1E') AND
      (STATUS = 1 OR
       STATUS = 0 AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM LIVE
                                  WHERE CRITERIA IN ('demo', 'all', '1', '1E') AND
                                        STATUS = 1));
```

To see how the above logic works, should there be `STATUS = 1` records, they would all be selected, and no `STATUS = 0` records would be included due to the exists logic.  In the case where no records match `STATUS = 1`, then the `STATUS = 0` records would be included, again due to the exists logic.

Comment: Why not `STATUS IN(...)` ?

Comment: I don't understand your comment.

Comment: You used criteria in(), but not status in()

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Appreciate.

Comment: @Strawberry the reason behind this was that in my question I had asked to prefer status 1 over 0. Since I cannot change the `ORDER BY` as I am doing it from id to show recents, basically he helped me with code that gets status 1 first, only if status 1 fails then status 0

Comment: @Strawberry No, _you're_ incorrect as well as your comments.

Answer (score 2):

If 1st query may return strictly 1 or 0 rows (not more) than simply

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM live 
WHERE status IN (1, 0) 
AND criteria IN ('demo', 'all', '1', '1E')
ORDER BY status DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

If 1st query may return more than 1 row then the optimal solution depends on MySQL version.

Comment: Thank you. So this code will prefer status 1 over 0 right? I mean I wish to show the running meetings first.

Comment: @VivaanMathur *So this code will prefer status 1 over 0 right?* Depends on ORDER BY expression.

Comment: Although this works as intended, I would use: `ORDER BY status = 1 DESC `, which points to the preferred value and could be changed to any other value.

Comment: @forpas When `WHERE status IN (1, 0)` is specified then `ORDER BY status = 1 DESC` simply adds excess compare without any profit...

Comment: This is why I said *this works as intended*. My point is that using `ORDER BY status = 1 DESC` adds to readability and scalability.